# How to stop/kill Airflow tasks from the UI

Tags: python, hadoop, airflow

How can I stop/kill a running task on Airflow UI? I am using `LocalExecutor`.
Even if I use `CeleryExecutor`, how do can I kill/stop the running task?

Answer (score 36):

In the DAGs screen you can see the running tasks:

[image]

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AX2ao.png)

On 'Recent Tasks' press the running icon and Airflow will automatically run the search query with the filters for the Dag Id and State equal to 'running' and show the results on the Task Instances screen (you can find it manually on the tab Browse > Task Instances).

There you can select the presented tasks and set them to another state or delete them.

Please notice that if the DAG is currently running, the Airflow scheduler will start again the tasks you delete. So either you stop the DAG first by changing its state or stop the scheduler (if you are running on a test environment).

Comment: Will it not restart the task even if i stop the scheduler and delete the task?

Comment: If you stop the scheduler and you do not want that task to run again, just set the task manually to the state "success" instead of deleting it. If you just delete it, the scheduler will run that task again.

Comment: I paused the DAG and deleted the records but the processes are still running. Is there a way to not only change the state according to the executor but also kill the underlying process?

Answer (score 24):

Set task to failed state:

1. Click task
   [image]
2. Set task to "Failed" state
   [image]
3. All subsequent tasks (if there are any) will also be marked as failed:
   [image]

Comment: "mark failed" is a dumb label for stopping a job... just call it "stop"!

Answer (score 15):

Simply set the task to failed state will stop the running task.

```
[2019-09-17 23:53:28,040] {logging_mixin.py:82} INFO - [2019-09-17 23:53:28,039] {jobs.py:2695} WARNING - State of this instance has been externally set to failed. Taking the poison pill.
[2019-09-17 23:53:28,041] {helpers.py:240} INFO - Sending Signals.SIGTERM to GPID 20977
```

Comment: This is the solution that worked for me. For others finding this post, more info can be found here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2285

Comment: Works for me also. Other answers imply non-deterministic, but you can check in the logs after changing the state.

Comment: This isn't the best plan, if the task has any retries left, it will keep retrying.

Answer (score 11):

from airflow gitter (@villasv)

> " Not gracefully, no. You can stop a dag (unmark as running) and clear
> the tasks states or even delete them in the UI. The actual running
> tasks in the executor won't stop, **but might be killed if the
> executor realizes that it's not in the database anymore**. "

Answer (score 7):

As menioned by Pablo and Jorge pausing the Dag will not stop the task from being executed if the execution already started. However there is a way to stop a running task from the UI but it's a bit hacky.

When the task is on `running` state you can click on `CLEAR` this will call `job.kill()` the task will be set to `shut_down` and moved to `up_for_retry` immediately hence it is stopped.

Clearly Airflow did not meant for you to clear tasks in `Running` state however since Airflow did not disable it either you can use it as I suggested. Airflow meant `CLEAR` to be used with `failed`, `up_for_retry` etc...  Maybe in the future the community will use this bug(?) and implement this as a functionality with "shut down task" button.

Answer (score 1):

AirFlow Version: v2.2.2 and above

1. Go to AirFlow home page
   and search you Dag.
2. Under the "Runs" status column press on the running status(green circle).

[image]

3. You can choose a specific DAG run or, in the check box above choose all.

[image]

Then on the "Action" button, choose your relevant action

[image]